# syslog rotation

Tags: syslog, logrotate

I wrote a small c app that uses the syslog c interface to write messages (from man 3 syslog):

```
void openlog(const char *ident, int logopt, int facility);
void syslog(int priority, const char *message, ...);
void closelog(void);
```

My question: I'm writing messages to LOCAL0 in `/var/log/local0.log`.  I also have cron calling logrotate on `/var/log/local0.log`.  I've noticed that after the rotation, my app continues writing to the file that was rotated out instead of the new `/var/log/local0.log`.

What is the best way to fix this with a postrotate script?

1. Easy, but not ideal: completely restart the rsyslog daemon.
2. Send and handle SIGHUP in my app.  This seems like the most appropriate solution.  But I'm not sure what I need to do when I get the HUP.  Do I just need to call closelog() then openlog()?

Answer (score 0):

Another decent workaround, which doesn't quite fit your situation but can be used "in a pinch" is the copytruncate option in logrotate. It means whatever is writing to the logfile does not need to be notified.